# Composite C1 pages not run on server

Tags: asp.net, hosting, c1-cms

I Created my site on WebMetrix -> Composite C1 and Upload all files which are generated by webmetrix but on server my pages are not running.
Any help.
Url :- http://newsolutionconsultancy.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When visiting http://newsolutionconsultancy.com/ is see "Index of /" showing all files and if I try opening http://newsolutionconsultancy.com/default.aspx I'm getting the source code of that file.

Your  web server is hot serving ASP.NET which is a requirement if you want to run Composite C1. You need to get another hosting option.

For system requirements see http://docs.composite.net/Getting-started/System-Requirements